# Como ir buscar informação a um App.config

Tags: c#, app.config

Eu estou a fazer um programa onde queria que fosse o utilizador a meter na variável o numero que precisa porque vai variar de computador para computador qual vai ser o numero que precisa.
Eu estou a usar o App.config para isso mas está me a enviar a o resultado em branco o condigo que estou a usar no App.Config é este

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
    <add key ="teste" value="1234"/>
</appSettings>
```

O código que eu estou a usar para receber este valor é este

```
string campoExtra = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["teste"];
MessageBox.Show(campoExtra);
```

E a MessageBox vem a branco eu não encontro qual é o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O `ConfigurationManager` vai tentar capturar as informações do config do executável em questão e não de DLL's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa abrir o arquivo de configuração antes

> ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

Atribui a leitura para uma váriavel e faz as leituras a partir dela

```
Configuration config= ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);


string campoExtra =  config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
MessageBox.Show(campoExtra);
```

Eu tenho uma classe que me auxilia nisso, se for do seu interesse segue abaixo:

```
public static class AppConfig
{
    private static Configuration config= ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);



    public static bool HasKey(string key)
    {
        return config.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys.Contains(key);
    }
    public static string Get(string key)
    {
        return config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
    }
    public static bool GetBolean(string key)
    {
        var value = config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return default(bool);
        return bool.Parse(value);
    }
    public static object GetObject(string key, Type type)
    {
        var method = type.GetMethod("Parse");
        if (method != null)
        {
            var v = method.Invoke(type, new[] { AppConfig.Get(key) });
            return v;
        }
        else
        {
            return AppConfig.Get(key);
        }

    }
    public static T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) });
        if (method != null)
        {
            var v = method.Invoke(typeof(T), new[] { AppConfig.Get(key) });
            return (T)v;
        }
        throw new Exception("O tipo não é convertivel");

    }

    public static void SetValue(string key, object value)
    {


        if (value == null)
        {
            if (!HasKey(key))
                config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, "");
            else
                config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = "";

        }
        else
        {
            if (!HasKey(key))
                config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(key, value.ToString());
            else                   
                config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value.ToString();
        }

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64195/discussion-on-answer-by-tiago-s-como-ir-buscar-informacao-a-um-app-config)

Answer (score 1):

Criei algumas configurações no App.Config  e busco a informação dele usando sua classe e trazendo para um `textbox`:

A configuração:

```xml
    ....
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Consulta.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="EnderecoBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value>local</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="PortaBD” serializeAs=”String">
                <value>porta</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="UsuarioBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value>usuario</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="SenhaBD" serializeAs="String">
                <value>senha</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Banco" serializeAs="String">
                <value>banco</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="CmdSQL" serializeAs="String">
                <value>comando</value>
            </setting>
        </Consulta.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

E na classse:

```
if (ComandoSQL.Text == String.Empty)    
{   
    string ComandoSQLRetorno = AppConfig.Get.(Key).CmdSQL.Value;
    ComandoSQL.Text = ComandoSQLRetorno;
}
```